# Whatsapp-web-js API returns response after a long time

Tags: javascript, express, whatsapp

I am trying to make an API to return groupChat ID with express framework and whatsapp-web-js library.
The first request to the endpoint after I start the server returns a response in 31 seconds but subsequent responses is stuck in a weird "loop" (not sure the right word to use).

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});

const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client({ authStrategy: new LocalAuth() });

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    client.on('ready', async () => {
        res.json(['test response'])
    });
});
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong but don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to my code and that solved it.
Here is my new code:

```
var express = require("express");
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');

const client = new Client({ authStrategy: new LocalAuth() });
var app = express();
client.initialize();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
client.on('ready', () => {
    res.json(['test response'])
});

app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    const chats = await client.getChats();
    res.json([chats]);
});
```